# Why is logistic regression a linear model?

Tags: regression, logistic, terminology

I want to know why logistic regression is called a linear model. It uses a sigmoid function, which is not linear. So why is logistic regression a linear model?

Comment: The logit of $\pi$ (the log of the odds) is linear in the parameters, but people don't refer to *logistic* regression as linear as far as I know. Can you cite who has said this?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica For example, in the Deep Learning book at page 169 (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html). In the book they note "Linear models, such as logistic regression and linear regression, are appealing....." I think they meant Generalized Linear Model for logistic regression.

Answer (score 55):

The logistic regression model is of the form
$$
\mathrm{logit}(p_i) = \mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \beta_2 x_{2,i} + \cdots + \beta_p x_{p,i}.
$$
It is called a *generalized* linear model not because the estimated probability of the response event is linear, but because the logit of the estimated probability response is a linear function of the <s>predictors</s> parameters.

More generally, the [Generalized Linear Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) is of the form
$$
\mathrm{g}(\mu_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1,i} + \beta_2 x_{2,i} + \cdots + \beta_p x_{p,i},
$$
where $\mu$ is the expected value of the response given the covariates.

**Edit:** Thank you whuber for the correction.

Comment: If you were to write "generalized linear" instead of "linear" and *parameters* instead of *predictors,* this would be correct.  (Many logistic regression models are *not* linear in the predictors.  For instance, no logistic regression with an interaction term will be linear in the predictors.)

Comment: You are correct, thank you. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: what is Pi there?

Comment: @whuber Why would an interaction term in a logistic regression wreck the linearity in the parameters when that is not the case for a linear regression? (I assume you mean predicting log-odds. If you mean predicting the probability, then I am confused how logistic regression could be linear in the parameters at all.)

Comment: @Dave In my parenthetical comment I wasn't writing about linearity of the *parameters:*  it was explicitly about the *predictors.*  Nowhere in the comment did I claim linearity of logistic regression models in either parameters or predictors.

Comment: I want to understand why the expected value of target variable, represented by b0 + b1*x1 ...   is equal to the logit(log of odds). I couldn't find any resources. Can you point me to paper or explain it.

Answer (score 9):

Logistic regression uses the general linear equation $Y=b_0+∑(b_i X_i)+\epsilon$. In linear regression $Y$ is a continuous dependent variable, but in logistic regression it is regressing for the probability of a categorical outcome (for example 0 and 1).

The probability of $Y=1$ is:
$$
P(Y=1) = {1 \over 1+e^{-(b_0+\sum{(b_iX_i)})}}
$$